# Incorporating CORS header in default media player

Tags: javascript, google-api, media-player, chromecast, android-cast-api

The [cast player API](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/cast.player.api#.CreateDashStreamingProtocol) provides 3 ways of streaming protocol(Hls, Dash, SmoothStreaming), if our media does not use any of these and uses progressive download, how can we incorporate our host has the updated CORS header into our media player like we would using one of the three streaming protocols,

```
protocol = cast.player.api.CreateSmoothStreamingProtocol(host);
window.player = new cast.player.api.Player(host);
            window.player.load(protocol);
```

Thanks!

Comment: So to be clear, you have an adaptive stream that is not hls, dash or SmoothStreaming? What type of stream is it?

Comment: @AliNaddaf I'm not exactly sure. All I want to do is to access an API endpoints with access url and access token in the headers set. Would all three work with regular mp4?

Comment: no, those three protocols are for adaptive streams.

Comment: If you are asking how you can add access token to the header, isn't it the same question as you asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33208823/2765813
to which I already responded?

Comment: @AliNaddaf I'm doing CORS authentication header now, and hoping to bind the host which has the CORS header with a media player. Thanks!

Comment: updateSegmentRequest is for adaptive not mp4.

Comment: @AliNaddaf Since updateSegmentRequest is only for adaptive streaming, how would we be able to pass in headers to access images, music, pdfs, etc? Is there any other way that's easier that using JQuery + AJax? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I provided a couple of suggestions in the other post that you asked the same type of questions. Think about it not as a chromecast receiver but as an html5 page; what would you do if you had such page and wanted to pass headers to show a video in your `<video/>` element? Do the same thing here; it is no different. And btw, there is no native PDF support.